# JQuery automatic slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, slideshow

I'm trying to just implement a simple automatic slideshow with JQuery on my webpage.
I followed this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5iPoJZjXnU. But, it seems that my fadeOut() and fadeIn() functions aren't working well. The code works but the transitions between images are too fast and not smooth.

Here's what i did:

added these lines in my head tags for upload jquery and jquery UI librairies:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

then, at the end of my body tags i simply added:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function galerie(){
        var active = $("#slideshow .active");
        var next = (active.next().length > 0) ? active.next() : $("#slideshow img:first");
        active.fadeOut(function(){
            active.removeClass("active");
        });
        next.fadeIn("slow").addClass("active");
    }
</script>
```

and call this function whenever i click on my h1 tag:

```
<h1 onClick="galerie()">Pure</h1>
```

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Edit : it's definitely the img tag who fadeOut and fadeIn not well because when i simply try : $(".active").fadeOut("slow"); it disapears without transition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem soleved, it was my html structure which wasn't right